# Bootstrap Modal Form submit error

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I know this question has many solutions in SO.But still I cant spot my mistake.The following is my bootstrap modal form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="../asset/modal/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<? if(isset($_POST["sendmail"]))
   echo "Form 1 have been submitted";
    ?>
<div class="container">

  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <? echo $token;  ?>
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" name="sendmail" >
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <textarea rows="8" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But whenever i submit the form it redirects to the index page of my project.Please Help me spotting my error.:-(

Comment: you should use a javascript listener if you don;t want to be redirected somewhere else

but if you want to be redirected on the same page put an action to your form with the same page that you use then have a detector if there is something submitted using isset()

as I can see your code is good but you only need the action on you form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its because you are not directing it anywhere...You need to write something like this:-

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" name="sendmail" action="page_name_here.php" >
```

So you need to add `action="page_name_here.php">`

If you want to stay on the same page then just write `action="#">`

Update:-

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="send">Send</button>
```

Add a `name` to the button `send` then in the Php:-

```
<? if(isset($_POST["send"]))
 echo "Form 1 have been submitted";
 ?>
```

This way when you click the `send` button everything in the form is submitted, since its a button of `type=submit`

Comment: i need to redirecting it to the same page.so there is no need of action..right?

Comment: Correct. You should do a `print_r` of just the `$_POST` superglobal in order to see exactly what was just posted.

Comment: i have solved it peter.the problem is because of a wierd condition in my code..anyway..thanks for helping..+1

Answer (score 0):

Use this for the submit button. Your button has not been named as `sendmail` for the POST so the info will not pass.

```
<? if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ))
   echo "Form 1 have been submitted";
?>
```

Add empty action as shown for the same page

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" name="sendmail" action="">
```

Comment: i have edited.. change the isset($_POST['sendmail'] to the edited code

Comment: There is no sendmail input that's the reason

Comment: actually sendmail is the name of my form

Comment: the form name is not need! the sumit button matters and inputs by the user. Forget form name.

Comment: if you copy the code i bet it will work, delete your sendmail part and copy the new change form action into action="". I bet it will work!